# No vector space of size $1$ and dimension $1$

Tags: vector-spaces

I am going to prove this by contradiction.

Suppose there is an $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$ with size $1$ and dimension $1$. That is, $|V| = 1$ (number of elements of $V$), and hence, $V = \{v\} = Span(v)$ and $v \ne \vec{0}$. However, in any vector space , it must contain the zero vector $\vec{0}$ because $cv \in V$, for all $c \in \mathbb{F}$. In particular, $0v = \vec{0}$. Hence, $v = \vec{0}$. But we assumed that $v \ne \vec{0}$. A contradiction. $\square$

Did I write the proof correctly?

Comment: That’s right. A vector space with one element is the zero vector space, which has dimension $0$ (as $\varnothing$ is a basis for it).

Comment: How do you define the "size" of a vector space to start with ?! Is it the number of elements, then it makes no sense to me, dimension $1$ space would have card(F) size, not sure that"s what you want.

Comment: There. I fixed it and edited it.

Comment: @zwim you can define vector spaces over finite fields and they will have a finite number of vectors. The point of the exercise is that the smallest finite vector space will have at least two elements.